# my entity file is not being included in the cakephp. Can someone help me?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

[image: This is my Folder Structure I have used the default Naming Convention]I was trying to hash the password but it turns out that  my entity file is not being included in the cakephp. Can someone help me why it is happening ???

When i run debug(get_included_file()); it does not show my User.php entity file.
and my User.php file content is :

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;


class User extends Entity
{

protected $_accessible = [
    'email' => true,
    'password' => true,
    'created' => true,
    'modified' => true,

];


protected $_hidden = [
    'password',
];

public function _setPassword($password) : ?string {

    if(strlen($password) > 0 ){

        return (new DefaultPasswordHasher())->hash($password);  
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Because is autoloading with composer, try ```composer dumpautoload```and where you run ```debug(get_included_file());```?

Comment: Is the file called `src/Model/Entity/User.php`? Things like `src/Model/Table/User.php` or `src/Model/Entity/Users.php` or `src/Model/Entity/user.php` won't work.

Comment: Thank you. but I am using the default Naming convention, see my Folder structure.

Comment: Maybe your Webserver has no rights to access the file for whatever reason?